# Getting the origin of all 3 axes at the same location

Tags: matlab

Here's an example 3D plot generated using `plot3`:

[image: plot]

My question is not how to generate this figure, it's how to place the axes.

The X-axis and Z-axis have their origin at the same point. But the Y-axis origin is at the front of the box making it coincident with x=1 on the X-axis.  I want the Y-axis origin at the same location of the X and Z axis origin. (Effectively putting the Y-axis behind the triangle.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[There is an undocumented way of doing it](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-axes-part-5-origin-crossover-and-labels), but you may need to tinker with the axes more, as putting them in a different position also messes with the logic of the labels and you may find them on top of the lines. There are ways to change the label position and relative position, but I will leave that for you to search.

```
surf(peaks+10)
ax=gca

ax.XAxis.FirstCrossoverValue  = 0;
ax.XAxis.SecondCrossoverValue = 0;
ax.YAxis.FirstCrossoverValue  = 0;
ax.YAxis.SecondCrossoverValue = 0;
```

[image]

Note I have not changed the "z" axis in this example, but you can easily do that too.

Comment: much appreciated!!

Comment: @pattiknuth cosnider accpeting the answer as valid